# Find area and the number of points inside contour

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, area

I generated a hotspot map as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpvW9.png) and now I want to calculate the area of each significant hotspot region. From the little research I've done, it seems as though I need to treat the contours as convex hulls and use Green's Theorem to calculate the area of the convex hulls.

However, I don't know how to translate this procedure into python code. Is there an easier method to achieve my goal? 
I'm thinking of isolating all convex hulls that contain intensity greater than 3.2 (that is light blue, green, yellow, orange and red colors) and finding the area enclosed in those contours.
I would also like to count the number of points contained in the convex hulls generated. 
Is there a simple way to do this using matplotlib?

Comment: Convex hulls won't work very well for you, because your polygons aren't convex. You need [shapely](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely). Get the contours out of `matplotlib` (they are lists of coordinates, basically) and make shapely `Polygon`s from them, then make shapely `Point`s for the points. See how you get on.